# Ficar mudando a cor da fonte somente com CSS

Tags: css, css3, css-transições

Tenho esse link que mostra/esconde o menu do site, quero chamar a atenção dos usuários para ele mudando a cor da fonte, é possível fazer somente com CSS?

```js
setInterval(function(){
  if ($('#toggleMenu').hasClass('colored')) {
    $('#toggleMenu').css('color','#FAFAFA');
    $('#toggleMenu').removeClass('colored');
  } else {
    $('#toggleMenu').css('color','#0069D9');
    $('#toggleMenu').addClass('colored');
  }
}, 2000);
```

```css
header {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0 5%;
}

#toggleMenu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  transition: color 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
<a id="toggleMenu" href="#" style="font-size: 2em"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível sim, basta trocar o `color` do ícone, pois ela é uma propriedade que pode ser animada sem problemas. Como o FontAwesome é uma fonte vc deve usar o `color` para isso, e com o `@keygrames` vc faz a animação. Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre os `@keyframes` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Um exemplo aplicando a técnica.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para simular o mesmo efeito que vc fez com jQuery a animação tem 4s, sendo que demora 2s para trocar a cor (50% da animação) e mais 2s para voltar para a cor original (outros 50% da animação). Pra entender melhor olha o código abaixo.

```css
.fa-bars {
 color: #FAFAFA;
 animation: bg 4s infinite;

}
@keyframes bg {
 50% {
  color: #0069D9;
 }
}

header {
 background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>
  <a id="toggleMenu" href="#" style="font-size: 2em"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
</header>
```

Comment: Brother, bem que você poderia postar sobre tecnologia no twitter ou em um blog heim? Acho que tem muito conteúdo pra postar...

Comment: @LaércioLopes obrigado amigo agradeço pelas palavras, é isso que motiva a gente a continuar colaborando. Eu até tenho vontade até de fazer um canal no Youtube, não por eu ter conteúdo de mais, mas pra poder passar um pouco do que vejo em inglês que sei que tem gente que não tem acesso tão fácil a essas conteúdo em português... Valeu a força []´s

Comment: Valeu, tamo junto!

Comment: Meu amigo! Será que tu sabe como resolver essa situação? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422999/adicionar-toast-bootstrap-empilhado-por-jquery

Comment: @LaércioLopes cara JS não é muito minha especialidade, acho que nessa não vou conseguir te ajudar... Mas lá na sua pergunta, tenta montar um exemplo mínimo que de para executar o seu problema, tipo o mínimo de código suficiente para fazer o toaster aparecer etc

Comment: Desculpa o incomodo cara, fiz mais testes aqui e consegui resolver!

Comment: Mesmo assim obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

no `css` existem os `@keyframes` onde possibilita a criação de animacões somente com html e css.

A Regra @keyframes
Ao especificar estilos CSS dentro da @keyframes regra, a animação irá gradualmente mudar a partir do estilo atual para o novo estilo em determinados momentos.

Para se ter uma animação para o trabalho, você deve ligar a animação a um elemento.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: changeColor 5s infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
  0%   {background-color: red;}
  25%  {background-color: yellow;}
  50%  {background-color: blue;}
  100% {background-color: green;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp